# Images are in same directory but one is displaying and other is not in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, backend, laravel-8

This line of code is working fine and image is displaying:

```
 <img src="{{asset('storage/students/1670740466.png')}}" width="300" height="300">
```

and this code below is not working although both are in the same directory. Images that are uploaded and stored through the form are not shown. Even if the name of that file is entered manually.

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/students/'. $members['image'] )}}" width="300" height="300">
```

I have no idea why it is happening.

Comment: Maybe $members['image'] should be: $members->image

Comment: No its not the case. Tried it and still not working

Comment: And what does `$members['image']` contain? Did you `dd($members['image'])`?

Comment: @brombeer It contains the name of the file that is stored in the directory but still its not displaying.

Comment: Have you checked the image key is coming in $members object? If so, then share me the response of $members object.

Comment: Maybe there's no file type so it's not showing. Have you try adding file type *sample* **PNG** ```src="{{asset('storage/students/'.$members['image'].'png' )}}"```